# Jenkins : Unable to Run Local Maven Project through Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration

I am new to CI. I am trying to run my local Selenium Project through Jenkins but it is getting failed with error. Here are the complete details:

OS - MAC OS
local POM xml Path:

```
Users/prakuma/git/NaveenPOMProject/Naveen_HybridPOM/pom.xml
```

I am not sure why is `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Naveen_POMHybrid` getting added before my `pom.xml` path.

I am attaching screen shot of Configuration and Global Setting of Jenkins.

1. Maven Global [image]
2. Global setting :[image]
3. Error:[image]

Comment: if you pay attention to the error, you provided path to no such file. Correct the path of POM.xml location.

Comment: Thanks for relpy. I am giving my Local location of POM.xml. Please check first Screen shot. But while executing , it is adding Jenkins Workspace Path before that due to which error is coming. But I dnt know why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps given below, which helped me to execute pom.xml successfully through jenkins on macOS.

1. Click on configuration (of project in jenkins)
2. Click on Build tab.
3. Keep Root POM as pom.xml
4. click on Advance.
5. search for "Use custom workspace"
6. check "Use custom workspace" , under Directory give your git dir location where pom.xml is there (eg: /Users/username/git/TestProject/TestProject).
7. Save.
8. Give all permission to directory(eg: /Users/username/git/TestProject)

[Please click here to get the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F8Fe.png)

Answer (score 0):

For working with maven jenkins plugin to use local project which is outside jenkins workspace. You can use [Copy Data To Workspace Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copy-data-to-workspace-plugin) which will move the code to workspace before maven execution.

Give your project folder to in `path to folder` variable.

Now in `Root pom`, simply leave it empty or just give pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

To make Jenkins find the `pom.xml` in a custom workspace ...

1. set the jobs `Root POM` to `pom.xml`
2. set `Use custom workspace` with the path to your `pom.xml` (e.g. `/Users/prakuma/git/NaveenPOMProject/Naveen_HybridPOM/` in this case)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can I set "Use custom workspace"?Where is it available in Jenkine

Comment: Thanks!! it has resolved somewhat but now i have differenent issue.

Comment: @PraveenKumar is the original issue solved? New post maybe for the other issue maybe or are related?

Comment: Actually, it look like that all of issues are coming because of user access issue on MAC. Right now, I am blocked to ask further question on this forum due to some rule. Thanks for helo